# npm install fails on jenkins due to file locking

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm

I have a powershell build script that runs `npm install` at some point.
I looked into the issue around the net, but I couldn't find anything helpful. I saw that somebody recommended putting an exception in `Windows Defender` for the jenkins folder because it was locking files. I did that, still no luck.

I don't think there are any locks on my part from the script, I'm just running npm install.
The strange thing is that this doesn't always happen, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

```
26610 verbose stack Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Jenkins\workspace\...\node_modules\.staging\highcharts-705cfa89\highcharts.src.js'
26612 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
26613 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
26614 verbose node v12.18.2
26615 verbose npm  v6.14.5
26616 error code EPERM
26617 error syscall unlink
26618 error path C:\Jenkins\workspace\...\node_modules\.staging\highcharts-705cfa89\highcharts.src.js
26619 error errno -4048
26620 error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Jenkins\workspace\...\node_modules\.staging\highcharts-705cfa89\highcharts.src.js'
26620 error  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Jenkins\workspace\...\node_modules\.staging\highcharts-705cfa89\highcharts.src.js'] {
26620 error   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Jenkins\workspace\...\node_modules\.staging\highcharts-705cfa89\highcharts.src.js'] {
26620 error     errno: -4048,
26620 error     code: 'EPERM',
26620 error     syscall: 'unlink',
26620 error     path: 'C:\\Jenkins\\workspace\\...\\node_modules\\.staging\\highcharts-705cfa89\\highcharts.src.js'
26620 error   },
26620 error   errno: -4048,
26620 error   code: 'EPERM',
26620 error   syscall: 'unlink',
26620 error   path: 'C:\\Jenkins\\workspace\\...\\node_modules\\.staging\\highcharts-705cfa89\\highcharts.src.js',
26620 error   parent: 'react'
26620 error }
26621 error The operation was rejected by your operating system.
26621 error It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
26621 error or that you lack permissions to access it.
26621 error
26621 error If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
26621 error permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
26621 error the command again as root/Administrator.
26622 verbose exit [ -4048, true ]
```

Comment: Have you checked for the proper permission of the folder.

Comment: What do you mean by proper? I'm on windows and I'll tell you as I see it. The `SYSTEM` has full control, also `<my_user>\Administrators`. Is more needed?

Comment: If it only happens sometimes, could you give more information about your jenkins setup - e.g. does this build always run on the same build agent? Are you running this stage in a container?

Comment: I don't know what relevant information I could give, there isn't anything unusual that I could think of. The builds run on the same agent, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who runs into this issue

The `package-lock.json` was the issue. We have a proget feed for npm packages that we use, but the `package-lock.json` had the registry set to the default npm registry. This is what caused the issues.

The solution is either to delete the `package-lock.json` file or to commit it after you run `npm install` with the correct registry.

Answer (score 0):

Try `yarn install` instead of `npm install`